# How can I extract an email address from a string using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some database upgrade to do, and I have to find email address from a description/tagline string.

String sample :

```
Fashion business\n\ud83c\udf38 DM for collab\n\ud83c\udf38email.adresse@gmail.com\n\ud83c\udf
```

This is what the string look like on Rails Console :
[image]

How can I extract "email.adresse@gmail.com" from this string?
Thanks

Comment: can you let me know how this string is generated ?

Comment: Why is `udf38` not part of the email? How do you tell?

Comment: @Nandhini it's a string made by the user, "ud83c" is a mobile smiley

Comment: @spickermann it's a mobile smiley

Comment: Can you just use regex? `([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/g` Also,  it'd be easier if you had some spaces between strings / emojis.

Comment: There are well known regular expressions, just use them http://emailregex.com/

Comment: @VeridianDynamics how can I pass the string with this regex plz ?

Comment: You will have to remove the emoji characters before processing. There should be some character separating the email from other characters (usually whitespace). In your sample string it is impossible to decide if `udf38` is part of email or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer found in a Java post but translated to rails it would be :

```
string = Fashion business\n\ud83c\udf38 DM for collab\n\ud83c\udf38email.adresse@gmail.com\n\ud83c\udf

email = string.scan(/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i)

email = email.adresse@gmail.com
```

Thanks for you answers

Comment: The extracted email is `udf38email.adresse@gmail.com` which is not expected.